# Помогите написать php скрипт обновления данных из сsv в базу mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin, csv

Помогите пожалуйста написать скрипт php для обновления данных в базе данных mysql. 
Суть такая есть файл "a.csv" в папке определенной на хостинге сайта с структурой 
*model*;*quantity*;*price*;
ad13;15;640
ad14;20;400

И так далее. 
Таблица в базе данных для обновления **oc_product**
В ней есть уже данные с столбцами model , quantity, price
Обновление должно идти по ключевому **model**. Если нету в базе , то пропускать.
 
Если есть, то обновить значения **quantity,price.**

Comment: а что так можно было?

Comment: А почему нет???

Comment: Скопировать файл на сервер. Загрузить во временную таблицу (LOAD DATA INFILE). Альтернативно - сразу LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE, если поддерживается. Затем выполнить обновление данных (UPDATE).

Comment: Смысл заключается в другом. Чтобы после автоматизировать этот процесс через cron задание я запущу этот скрипт на выполнение каждый n-часов.